# Day counter program (racket)

Tags: racket

I need to do a program which can count all days that have been passed since 2000's until the date that the user enter in the input.

Current code.

```
#lang racket
(define (bisiesto year)
   (cond (= (remainder year 4) 0) (void))
)

(define day 0)
(define month 0)
(define cyear 0)

(define (count)
  (display "Enter day: ")
  (set! day(read))
  (newline)
  (display "Enter month: ")
  (set! month(read))
  (newline)
  (display "Enter year: ")
  (set! cyear(read))
  (newline)

  (cond
     ((and(> day 0)(>= 31))
```

I have no idea how to continue this program, I don't know very well racket language.

PD: Sorry if my English it's not good enough, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need function [`find-seconds`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fdate..rkt%29._find-seconds%29%29) from [`racket/date`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html#%28mod-path._racket%2Fdate%29) library:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/date)

(define (day-count day month year)
  (let ((diff (- (find-seconds 0 0 0 day month year)
                 (find-seconds 0 0 0 1 1 2000))))
    (if (> 0 diff)
        "Inserted date is before 1. 1. 2000."
        (/ diff (* 60 60 24)))))

(define (read-with-prompt text)
  (display text)
  (flush-output)
  (read))

(define (run-program)
  (day-count
   (read-with-prompt "Enter day (1-31): ")
   (read-with-prompt "Enter month (1-12): ")
   (read-with-prompt "Enter year: ")))
```

Start with `(run-program)` and enter some numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your help but just one more question, how can I made this program with recursion?